# Probability of subset occurring

Tags: probability

Suppose I had 10 people who all had an equal chance of getting one of 7 prizes in a game. Let's also suppose that 5 of these people were friends. How would I calculate the probability that all 5 of the friends gets one of only 7 prizes? In other words, the amount of prizes is greater than the amount of people in the friend group but less than the amount of contestants. I understand permutations and combinations but I'm not comfortable with this one for some reason. Thanks if anyone knows!

Comment: It's just the binomial theorem...what are you struggling with?

Comment: It is unclear, let us put names on the players, 1,2,3,4,5,a,b,c,d,,e. Assume 1,2,3,4,5 are the friends. Now prizes are distributed. (Is there a difference between the prices? Each person becomes at most one prize?) We want the probabiltiy that each person among 1,2,3,4,5 gets (at least) one price?

Comment: No difference between prizes. We want the probability that all 5 get one of 7 identical prizes. I guess I thought, because it was among 10 contestants it was different. Not sure I'm as comfortable with binomial theorem as I thought I suppose.